# Asking to Install Update 1709 When Already on Version 1709

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1709

I have just recently made a fresh install of Windows 10 on my computer. After I finished the install I went to 'Windows Update' in settings and continuously checked for updates and restarted my computer as prompted to try to get to the latest version. After quickly installing some basic updates I finally reached the point where it was asking me to install version 1709. However it seems that I have gotten stuck in an infinite loop where I it downloads and installs version 1709, I restart it and then it asks me to install version 1709 again.

I am pretty sure that version 1709 is already installed on my computer as that's what shows up when I run `winver` and what I see in 'About'. How do I let Windows know that I already installed the update and have it stop bugging me about it in the settings and Windows Defender?

Note: Running `sfc /scannow` shows that there are no integrity violations.

Comment: post a picture of Winver.exe so that we see which version you currently run

Answer (score -1):

Now the latest build is Windows 10 1709 (OS build 16299.334). Just download the latest cumulative update package KB4089848 and install it manually to keep it up to date.

You can download it from Microsoft Update catalog:

http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4089848

**Note:** Choose the proper version applied to your Windows.

Afterwards, your Windows 10 1709 won't check update continuously.